# Selenium concurrent findElement command

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Can I run multiple findElement in parallel/ concurrently to read multiple Elements from a Page?

If yes how can I do that?

I tried with running a Thread in background but it did not work.

I would like to get details of multiple elements and perform some actions within few seconds?

Thanks,
Deepak

Comment: Do these element have anything in common or are they distinct?

Comment: They are distinct.

Comment: Update the question with your code trials

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is "no".

The Selenium server is single threaded, so only allows one request to be processed as once.

Therefore 2 concurrent requests to find different elements which be processed sequentially, and therefore little is achieved by threading Selenium requests